# How to convert a table to a named list where each list element is a row from the table?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```r
fruits <- tibble(
  fruit = c("apple", "orange", "pear", "pineapple", "blueberry"),
  color = c("red", "orange", "green", "yellow", "blue"),
  climate = c("temperate", "(sub)tropical", "temperate", "(sub)tropical", "temperate"),
  sugar_per_100g = c(10.39, 9.35, 9.75, 9.85, 9.96)
)
```

| fruit | color | climate | sugar_per_100g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | red | temperate | 10.39 |
| orange | orange | (sub)tropical | 9.35 |
| pear | green | temperate | 9.75 |
| pineapple | yellow | (sub)tropical | 9.85 |
| blueberry | blue | temperate | 9.96 |

Now I want to create some sort of lookup list where each list element contains the data for a certain fruit in the data set.

The resulted list should be this:

```
## $apple
## $apple$color
## [1] "red"
## 
## $apple$climate
## [1] "temperate"
## 
## $apple$sugar_per_100g
## [1] 10.39
## 
## 
## $orange
## $orange$color
## [1] "orange"
## 
## $orange$climate
## [1] "(sub)tropical"
## 
## $orange$sugar_per_100g
## [1] 9.35
## 
## ...
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Why is it that you ask a question and then instantaneously provide an answer?

Comment: To share what I have found out, in case someone else searches for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be boiled down into 3 basic steps:

1. Remove the column that will be used for naming from the data, because we don't want it to be a sub element of the list. Keep in mind, that the values of the naming column must be unique.
2. Create (sub)lists for each each row or in the table. Or in the variant: transpose the data set (output would be a list).
3. Apply names to the top level list elements. The names originate from the naming column.

```r
fruits %>%
  select(-fruit) %>%         # remove column that will be used for naming
  pmap(list) %>%             # convert rows to list
  set_names(fruits$fruit)    # name list with naming column
```

Variant:

```r
fruits %>%
  select(-fruit) %>%
  transpose(.names = fruits$fruit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a one-liner in base R:

```r
setNames(lapply(asplit(fruits[-1], 1), as.list), fruits[[1]])
#> $apple
#> $apple$color
#> [1] "red"
#> 
#> $apple$climate
#> [1] "temperate"
#> 
#> $apple$sugar_per_100g
#> [1] "10.39"
#> 
#> 
#> $orange
#> $orange$color
#> [1] "orange"
#> 
#> $orange$climate
#> [1] "(sub)tropical"
#> 
#> $orange$sugar_per_100g
#> [1] " 9.35"
#> 
#> 
#> $pear
#> $pear$color
#> [1] "green"
#> 
#> $pear$climate
#> [1] "temperate"
#> 
#> $pear$sugar_per_100g
#> [1] " 9.75"
#> 
#> 
#> $pineapple
#> $pineapple$color
#> [1] "yellow"
#> 
#> $pineapple$climate
#> [1] "(sub)tropical"
#> 
#> $pineapple$sugar_per_100g
#> [1] " 9.85"
#> 
#> 
#> $blueberry
#> $blueberry$color
#> [1] "blue"
#> 
#> $blueberry$climate
#> [1] "temperate"
#> 
#> $blueberry$sugar_per_100g
#> [1] " 9.96"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nice answer, upvoted, but I think it's better to have the `sugar_per_100g` domain with numeric values instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
> setNames(lapply(1:nrow(fruits), function(k) as.list(fruits[k, -1])), fruits[[1]])
$apple
$apple$color
[1] "red"

$apple$climate
[1] "temperate"

$apple$sugar_per_100g
[1] 10.39


$orange
$orange$color
[1] "orange"

$orange$climate
[1] "(sub)tropical"

$orange$sugar_per_100g
[1] 9.35


$pear
$pear$color
[1] "green"

$pear$climate
[1] "temperate"

$pear$sugar_per_100g
[1] 9.75


$pineapple
$pineapple$color
[1] "yellow"

$pineapple$climate
[1] "(sub)tropical"

$pineapple$sugar_per_100g
[1] 9.85


$blueberry
$blueberry$color
[1] "blue"

$blueberry$climate
[1] "temperate"

$blueberry$sugar_per_100g
[1] 9.96
```